# Как и чем собирать документацию по базе данных?

Tags: база-данных, oracle, документация

В наличии БД `Oracle`. На протяжении примерно 20 лет разные люди поучаствовали в написании большого количества хранимого кода, с нетривиальными решениями и загадочными взаимосвязями. Документации как и требований по всему этому делу нет.

Хочется в автоматическом режиме собрать как можно больше информации о БД(таблицы, процедуры, тригерры и т.д.) в удобо читаемом виде. Какие объекты какие таблицы модифицируют и от каких зависят, а так же последовательности вызовов.
Для построения диаграмм по таблицам есть немало решений(например Oracle Data Modeler, ERwim или PowerDesigner), но вот касательно хранимого кода найти удалось мало:

1. PLSQL Developer умеет строить простенькую HTML документацию на основе указанных пакетов в страшненьком виде.
2. Консольная утилита [pldoc](http://pldoc.sourceforge.net/maven-site/index.html). Умеет строить что то похожее на `javadoc` при наличии комментариев к коду в  нужном формате. `Open Source` и можно доработать.

Отсюда вопрос:

**Какую информацию и в каком виде имеет смысл собирать об объектах БД и какие для этого еще существуют инструменты?**

Comment: [all_dependencies](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1041.htm#i1576452) смотрели уже? Дальше иерархический запрос.

Comment: Хочется свести это в документы. Например HTML'ка в которой будет пакет с процедурами и функциями. При этом напротив каждой процедуры будет список объектов от которых она зависит. И на каждый можно нажать и провалиться дальше. Я пока сам смутно представляю, что вообще хочу

Comment: HTMLку можно генерить с помощью [SQL/XML](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB4987). А со "смутой" надо бороться... Можно еще апекс приспособить как интерфейс.

Comment: @Dmitry  в любом случае придется целиком создать свое решение. Я рассматриваю такой подход как альтернативный вариант. Но все же было бы неплохо найти готовые решение или хотя бы на них посмотреть для более лучшей реализации своего.

Comment: Кстати, вам еще неплохо бы начать логировать, какие процедуры и таблицы используются. Может ведь оказаться так, что код есть, а необходимости в нем нет, и его последний раз вызывали 10 лет назад.

Comment: Об этом тоже думаю. Но как к этой задаче подступиться тоже не особо понятно. Включать оракловый аудит не хочется, переживаю что БД просядет слишком сильно. Эта тема достойна отдельного вопроса.

Comment: Можно вставить логирование в каждую процедуру (но это очень много работы и не труъ в любом случае), а если весь код распихан по пакетам - то в секцию инициализации пакета. Тогда логирование будет срабатывать намного реже и можно будет найти целые пакеты, которые вообще не работают (если такие есть).

Comment: Скорее всего, надо комбинировать различные готовые решения. Если код запущен, то чуда не произойдёт и  будет в "сбор информации в полу-автоматическом режиме". Также  можно посмотреть в сторону анализатора кода на каком-либо скриптовом ЯП, perl например, но готового решения мне не встречалось.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Какую информацию и в каком виде имеет смысл собирать об объектах БД

1. Сначала построить модель данных с помощью средств Oracle. Интересуют конечные точки входа, которые вызываются не из самого Oracle, а из вне. То есть, ищем непустые таблицы, а также процедуры и функции, которые вызываются не из других процедур и функций, а откуда-то из вне.
2. Анализ пользовательского(ских) приложений на предмет вызова из него(них) этих конечных точек. То есть, ищем, какие таблицы и колонки в них заполняются и какие читаются, ищем вызовы процедур и функций.
3. Если конечная точка ни от куда не вызывается - устанавливаем для нее префикс `old_`.
4. Повторить пункты 1-3, исключив из поиска объекты с префиксом `old_` до тех пор, пока ничего лишнего не останется.
5. Если связь установлена: создаем описание связи в виде: Пользовательское приложение - Представление данных - Объект данных - Внутренние связи в объекте.
6. Если очистка базы в планы не входит - исключить пункты 3-4.

---

Для описания связей в БД, лучше написать отдельное приложение (которое само по себе будет еще одной БД). На его основе в будущем легче будет писать доработки к текущей БД.

---

К сожалению ни одно, известное мне, приложение не может полностью выполнить все эти задачи. Его придется либо написать, либо делать все в полу-ручном режиме, в тесном сотрудничестве с пользователями. А как показывает мой личный опыт - придется писать приложение, которое будет работать в полу-ручном режиме, в тесном сотрудничестве с пользователями.

Answer (score 3):

Есть утилиты для генерации описаний.

Вот например одна из известных: [dataedo](https://dataedo.com/)

Она позволяет автогенерировать описания, редактировать шаблоны итд и экспортировать в разные форматы.
[Вот пример результата ее работы.](https://dataedo.com/download/AdventureWorks.pdf)